# How to detect two entities at the same coordinate with same name tag?

Tags: minecraft-commands

Actually, when I'm putting the command

```
/execute @e[name=Mark] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[name=Mark] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @e[name=Mark] detect 1
```

I'm expecting that if only these two same name entities where together then the scoreboard will be "1". But it doesn't, cause it turns to "1" even if I summon only a single "mark" in my world.

Comment: Nice try! However, you're experiencing this because `@e` selects _all_ instances of that entity, including itself, which is the same reason why `@p` executed by a player is himself. Try putting some sort of secondary identifier.

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nice try! However, you're experiencing this because @e selects all instances of that entity, including itself, which is the same reason why @p executed by a player is himself.

---

## Try making your detection additive.

In a repeater (as in not Redstone Repeater, but the Repeater and Chain Command Blocks) chain, do:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[name=Mark] detect 0
/execute @e[name=Mark] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[name=Mark,r=__] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players add @e[name=Mark] detect 1
```

Now, all you need to do to select all the `Mark`s that are nearby (within `r=__` blocks) is to test for anyone with a score of at least 1.

```
/execute @e[score_min_detect=1] ...
```

---

### Why this works?

This is because if we are to only have one `Mark`, his score would always be one since he's the only one executing it.

If there are multiple nearby `Mark`s, then the `/scoreboard players add` will stack and obviously yielding scores greater than 1.

As for why wouldn't this go into infinity? It's because we reset it after every redstone tick:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[name=Mark] detect 0
```

Comment: @ArJhi If my answer is the correct answer, please mark it as correct using the green check mark. Otherwise please state what you need clarification.